# Row_Number/Partition By, getting all result sets that are more than one value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm using ROW_NUMBER() and PARTITION BY to create a table that looks like this:

```
   VALUE     ID   ROWNUM 
    A       4525     1
    B       4526     1
    C       4527     1
    D       4530     1
    E       4530     2
    F       4530     3
    G       4531     1
    H       4531     2
```

I want to get rid of the partitions that consist of only one value. A, B, and C will be gone, but D through H will stay because they're in partitions that contain more than one value. In other words, what can I do to my query to make the results look like this:

```
   VALUE     ID    ROWNUM 
    D       4530     1
    E       4530     2
    F       4530     3
    G       4531     1
    H       4531     2
```

I can't filter by ROWNUM > 1 because I want to keep some of the columns where ROWNUM = 1, but figuring out how to keep *only* some of those columns is stumping me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

However you are calculating `rownum`, also calculate `count(*)`:

```
select value, id, rownum
from (select t.*, 
             row_number() over (partition by . . . order by . . . ) as rownum,
             count(*) over (partition by . . . ) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where cnt > 1;
```

The `partition by` should be the same for the two window functions.